# One http client for instance of application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to use http client as effiencet as possible in .net core 3.0 but it appears still to use a client per service, for example, I have the following StockSevices Class which will house all my calls to do with stock I am using asp.net core 3.0 at present

```
public class StockServices
{


    public HttpClient Client { get; }

    public StockServices(HttpClient client)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseApiUrl);
        // GitHub API versioning
          // GitHub requires a user-agent
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
            "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

        Client = client;

    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<RoundTableERPDal.Models.Stock>> GetAspNetDocsIssues()
    {
        var response = await Client.GetAsync(
            "/Stock/All");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RoundTableERPDal.Models.Stock>>(result);


    }
```

I have placed this in my startup file but what I don't get is how do I pass a global HTTP client as we are meant to use the same one to stop the degradation of calls for many ports open.

In My Startup cs.

```
  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);

        services.AddHttpClient("externalservice", c =>
        {
            // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>

        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Api For RoundTable A Complete ERP for warehouse managment", Version = "v1" });
        });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added a *Named* client when what you need is a *Typed* client

```
//...

services.AddHttpClient<StockServices>(client => {
    // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseApiUrl);
    // GitHub API versioning
    // GitHub requires a user-agent
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});

//...
```

If `StockServices` is eventually abstracted the same can be done for its interface

```
services.AddHttpClient<IStockServices, StockServices>(client => {
    // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseApiUrl);
    // GitHub API versioning
    // GitHub requires a user-agent
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

Where the service looks like

```
public class StockServices: IStockServices {    
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public StockServices(HttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<RoundTableERPDal.Models.Stock>> GetAspNetDocsIssues() {
        using(var response = await client.GetAsync("/Stock/All")) {

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RoundTableERPDal.Models.Stock>>(result);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Reference [How to use Typed Clients with HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-httpclientfactory)

Comment: Thank u for the in-depth answer How Would I call the function than say for an ajax get method of a grid to avoid the client to be duplicated even with your example I would need a startup like the above for warehouselocation model and all my othe models as well is that good practice.